# Java - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

This small program will take two inputted numbers and find the difference from each other. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to fix this.

Errors:

> Range.java:3: error: class range is public, should be declared in a file named range.java
>   public class range

and

> Range.java:16: error: no suitable method found for println(String,int,String,int,String)
>           System.out.println("The number of values in the range from", n1, "to", n2, "is: ");

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class range
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter two integers: ");

        int n1, n2;


        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        n1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        n2 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The number of values in the range from", n1, "to", n2, "is: ");
        System.out.println(n2 - n1);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Your class is named `range`, but it is in a file named `Range.java`. The names of the class and the file it is within must match. Either change the class name to `public class Range` or change the file name to `range.java`. Also, you should read about String concatenation to solve your second error.

Comment: what dont you understand about the error messages?

Comment: println takes a single `String` argument: System.out.println("The number of values in the range from "+ n1 + " to " + n2+ " is: ");

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

The error messages are clear.

First of all, put your code in a file named `range.java` and I highly suggest you change it to Range instead.

Then, change your println line to:
`System.out.println("The number of values in the range from "+ n1 + " to "+ n2 + "is: ");`

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

> Range.java:3: error: class range is public, should be declared in a
>   file named range.java public class range

The file where this class is written needs to be called `range.java`, since `range` class is public.

> Range.java:16: error: no suitable method found for
>   println(String,int,String,int,String) System.out.println("The number
>   of values in the range from", n1, "to", n2, "is: ");

`System.out.println()` takes only a single parameter, while you are attempting to pass 5.

If you want to output several values in one line, it's better to use `format()`:

```
System.out.format("The number of values in the range from %d to %d is:", n1, n2");
```